# Removing Event Listeners on before the function is re-run

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, addeventlistener

I want to create a scoring board for darts.
In this game, a number of players take turns in throwing 3 darts. Every dart scores an amount of points.
I've created buttons which correspond to the actual targets thrown on the dart board.
Example of such a button:
Player throws 1, so this button is clicked: 1.

My problem is combining the **event listeners** on the buttons with automatically switching to the next player when the turn is over.

With the code below, it seems that the button clicks remain associated to the previouos player, so when the second player throws, these throws are also counted for the first player...

So after the first round (every player has thrown 3 times, so 12 button clicks, player1 has totalArrows = 21, which is wrong obviously, this should be 3.

I've tried to extract the handleClick function from the event listener, but then I can't seem to pass the button as a parameter, which is needed for the score.

My code:

```
// Player
//  remaining = how much of the score remains after each throw.
//  totalArrows = how many arrows has player thrown.
let player1 = { name: 'Steven', remaining: 501, totalArrows: 0};
let player2 = { name: 'Tom', remaining: 501, totalArrows: 0};
let player3 = { name: 'Nico', remaining: 501, totalArrows: 0};
let players = [player1, player2, player3];

// The buttons that can be clicked for scoring
const targetButtons = document.querySelectorAll(".target");

let playersIndex = 0;
let throws = 0;

function playerTurn() {
    let currentPlayer = players[playersIndex];
        
    targetButtons.forEach((button) => {
    
        button.addEventListener('click', function handleClick() {
        
            if (throws < 3 ) {
                currentPlayer.totalArrows++;
                const scoreThisThrow = parseInt(this.textContent);
                currentPlayer.remaining -= scoreThisThrow:
                throws++;
                
                if (throws === 3) {
                    button.removeEventListener("click", handleClick);
                    playersIndex = (playersIndex + 1) % players.length;
                    throws = 0;
                    playerTurn()
                }
            }
        });
    });
}

// Start the game
playerTurn()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is off. As you have it, you only evaluate whether `players === 3` when `players < 3`. Which, of course, can never happen: `players`
can never equal 3 if `players` is less than 3. So take your `if players === 3` out of the other `if` block.

That should solve your problem, and without having to remove your event listener. I'm also not seeing what you are doing with your `totalArrows` property. I'm presuming that its use is outside of the scope of the problem you've defined here. But if all you were using it for was to attempt to figure out why only one player was getting all the throws, then you can safely remove it.

By the way, if you are not calling `handleClick` specifically from outside your `addEventListener` setup, you don't need to give it a name: `button.addEventListener('click', function(e) {` and so on.

Note that it is also usual to add a parameter to the function, usually `e` or `event`. This gives a reference to the `Event` object that the `button` element implements. So, for example, if you want to prevent the normal behavior for the event, you can put `e.preventDefault`. A common example of when you do this is when you have a button of type `submit` inside a form, and want to override the default behavior of the button.

Comment: The totalArrows is indeed outside of the scope. I left it there for troubleshooting.
To be clear, all players get throws, but the previous players also get the throws after their turn.

I've changed the code, but the problem remains.
also, in the if-statement I add 1 to throws, so after that throws can be 3, and the second if statement will be true ?

Comment: I have changed the code, but the problems remain.
button.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
 e.preventDefault();
 if (throws < 3) { ... }

 if (throws === 3) {
 playersIndex = (playersIndex + 1) % players.length;
 throws = 0;
 playerTurn()
}

Comment: @ESDEE First, I don't think you need to use `preventDefault`. I was just using that to illustrate the use of the `Event` object. Next, are you telling me that you get exactly the same behavior as before, after moving the `if (throws === 3)` out of the other `if` block? That sounds off to me. Perhaps you can post your modified code?

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to make it work. The code absolutley needs optimizing/cleaning, but the game is working in regards to automatically proceeding to the next player after three throws, without any arrow or remaining points issues.

I've incorporated the scoring system normally used in a darts X01 game:

- A game is won when a certain amount of sets are won.
- A set is won when a certain amount of legs are won.
- A leg is won when a player reaches 0 or less.

The code below:

```
// remaining = how much of the score remains after each throw.
// totalArrows = how many arrows has player thrown.
// legs = number of legs won.
// sets = number of sets won.
const player1 = { name: 'Steven', remaining: 501, totalArrows: 0, legs: 0, sets: 0};
const player2 = { name: 'Tom', remaining: 501, totalArrows: 0, legs: 0, sets: 0};
const player3 = { name: 'Nico', remaining: 501, totalArrows: 0, legs: 0, sets: 0};
const players = [player1, player2, player3];

// The buttons that can be clicked for scoring
const targetButtons = document.querySelectorAll(".target");
const numPlayers = players.length;
const totalLegs = 3;
const totalSets = 3;
let playersIndex = 0;
let currentPlayer = players[playersIndex];
let throws = 0;
let gameFinished = false

function playerTurn() {
                
    targetButtons.forEach((button) => {
    
        button.addEventListener('click', function handleClick() {
        
            if (throws < 3 ) {
                currentPlayer.totalArrows += 1;
                const scoreThisThrow = parseInt(this.textContent);
                currentPlayer.remaining -= scoreThisThrow:
                throws++;
                
                if (throws === 3 || currentPlayer.remaining < 1) {
                    // TODO: Bust rule
                    // TODO: Double out
                    if (currentPlayer.remaining < 1) {    // Player wins leg
                        currentPlayer.legs += 1;
                        if (currentPlayer.legs === totalLegs) {    // Player wins set
                            currentPlayer.sets += 1;
                            // Reset leg count
                            players.forEach((player) => {
                                player.legs = 0
                            });
                            if (player.sets === totalSets) {    // Player wins the game
                                gameFinished = true;
                            } else {
                                playersIndex = (playersIndex + 1) % numPlayers;
                                currentPlayer = players[playersIndex];
                                throws = 0;
                                return;
                            }
                        }
                        playersIndex = (playersIndex + 1) % numPlayers;
                        currentPlayer = players[playersIndex];
                        throws = 0;
                        return;
                    }
                    if (throws === 3) {
                        playersIndex = (playersIndex + 1) % players.length;
                        currentPlayer = players[playersIndex];
                        throws = 0;
                        return;
                    }
                    if (!gameFinished) {
                        playerTurn();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    });
}
    
playerTurn()
```